# Reduce and sum array of objects (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js

**My data**:

```
arr: [],
models: [
    { id: 1, name: "samsung", seller_id: 1, count: 56 },
    { id: 1, name: "samsung", seller_id: 2, count: 68 },
    { id: 2, name: "nokia", seller_id: 2, count: 45 },
    { id: 2, name: "nokia", seller_id: 3, count: 49 }
]
```

**Expected Arr:**

```
arr: [
    { id: 1, name: "samsung", count: 124 },
    { id: 2, name: "nokia", count: 94 }
]
```

It's my code to simplify models by removing repeated `id`:

```
this.models.forEach(mdl => {
    if (!this.arr.some(obj => obj.id === mdl.id)) {
        this.arr.push(mdl);
    }
});
```

But I can't sum `count`s.
How can I do that?

Comment: Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce()`:

```js
var models = [
    { id: 1, name: "samsung", seller_id: 1, count: 56 },
    { id: 1, name: "samsung", seller_id: 2, count: 68 },
    { id: 2, name: "nokia", seller_id: 2, count: 45 },
    { id: 2, name: "nokia", seller_id: 3, count: 49 }
];

var arr = models.reduce((acc, item) => {
  let existItem = acc.find(({id}) => item.id === id);
  if(existItem) {
    existItem.count += item.count;
  } else {
    acc.push(item);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(arr);
```

So, for your code, you can use `this.arr` and `this.models` replacing those variables from above which will look something like:

```
this.arr = this.models.reduce((acc, item) => {
  let existItem = acc.find(({id}) => item.id === id);
  if(existItem) {
    existItem.count += item.count;
  } else {
    acc.push(item);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values` instead of `some`. Inside the reduce callback create an object with key as `id` and value from the models. Then use `Object.values` to create an array of the values

```js
let models = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "samsung",
    seller_id: 1,
    count: 56
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "samsung",
    seller_id: 2,
    count: 68
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "nokia",
    seller_id: 2,
    count: 45
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "nokia",
    seller_id: 3,
    count: 49
  }
]
let data = models.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (!acc[curr.id]) {
    acc[curr.id] = curr;
  } else {
    acc[curr.id].count += curr.count

  }
  return acc;
}, {})
console.log(Object.values(data))
```